# Category Menu Missing from homepage after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, menu

I have upgraded Magento from 1.9.2.0 to 1.9.4.2 through Magento connect manager.
The upgrade process went successfully and everything loaded fine except the Category Menu from the Homepage. The category menu from the home page is missing. I have a Mega Menu module and tried to disable it but no luck. How can I recover the menu?
Connect Manager also could login after upgrade. The login page just refreshes after login and return the below URL
https://magento-url/downloader/index.php?A=
Before I was able to login by changing from https to http but that also no longer works after upgrading.

Jais

Comment: Did you try to reindex after upgrade ?

Comment: Yes , I did that but no luck..

Comment: Did you checked any system log or exception in var/log ?